# Vectorizing and assigning structs and fields

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, vectorization

I would like to vectorize operations with structs and have spent some hours searching but I couldn’t find the solution.
I have a struct as follows:

```
clear all

n= 10;

for i=1:n

    mystruct(i).x    = i;

    mystruct(i).y    = i;

    mystruct(i).z    = 0;

end
```

I want to add all x to all y values and assign them to z.

This works:

```
test1 = [mystruct.x] + [mystruct.y];

test2 = arrayfun(@(a)mystruct(a).x+mystruct(a).y,1:n);
```

However, assigning the array doesn’t:

```
mystruct.z = [mystruct.x] + [mystruct.y];

mystruct.z = mystruct.x + mystruct.y;
```

I can generate a new struct:

```
mystruct2  = struct('z',num2cell ([mystruct.x]+[mystruct.y]));
```

But the next operation again doesn't work:

```
mystruct.z = mystruct2.z;
```

I could of course use a for loop:

```
for i=1:n

    mystruct(i).z  =  mystruct(i).x   + mystruct(i).y;

end
```

But that’s not what I want as this would make my code quite nasty and will not work for parallel operations using "parfor".
How can I perform this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to use the [deal](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html?refresh=true) function, which is used to distribute inputs to outputs and works with structures starting with MATLAB 7.

With appropriate use of [square brackets], you can use this:

```
[mystruct2.z] = deal([mystruct(1:n).x] + [mystruct(1:n).y]);
```

which outputs:

```
ans =

     2     4     6
```

Yay!

Comment: FYI, If n is the length of mystruct then mystruct(1:n).x and mystruct.x are the same.